# ListActivity with selectable Items

Tags: android

To improve usability for blind users, I need a ListActivity with an OnItemSelected method to add stuff like vibration or sounds when a specific listitem is selected. 
Therefore I have extended the ListActivity class and added the following methods:

```
protected void onListItemSelected(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
}

private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mOnSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        onListItemSelected((ListView)parent, v, position, id);          
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }
};
```

Now, when I create an instance of my new Class SelectableListActivity and override the onListItemSelected method, still nothing happens. Any Ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: A very common problem with new Android developers is to rely on ListView.getSelectedItemPosition(). In touch mode, this method will return INVALID_POSITION. You should instead use click listeners (see setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) or the choice mode (see setChoiceMode(int)).

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html

Comment: well in this particular case i need a listener for selection, since the view is operated by physical keys and i need to give some form of feedback before an item is selected via click.

Comment: What is the content of your list items?  Some controls, like checkboxes, will intercept the onClick.

Comment: Even that you're using the keyboard this doesn't mean that your device is in touch mode, I believe that this could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to override onContentChanged() and assign my listener to the ListView.

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

private Vibrator vibrator;
private ListView mList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    setContentView(R.layout.station_list);
    // do some other stuff
}

@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();
    mList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mList.setOnItemSelectedListener(mOnSelectedListener);
}

private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mOnSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        onListItemSelected((ListView)parent, v, position, id);          
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // nothing to do here...            
    }
};

    protected void onListItemSelected(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    vibrator.vibrate(100);
}

    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    vibrator.vibrate(100);
    Cursor c = cursor;
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeOtherActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(StationsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN));
            dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN));
        }
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP));
            dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP));
        }
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER));
            dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER));
        }
        return true;
    default: 
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

}

This way I was able to create a ListView that is usable without the touchscreen and thus possible for e.g. blind people to interact with.